# how can a div be made a background for another div

Tags: html, css

The original idea was to have one div with this style:

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
```

However, I discovered that rgba is only supported by newer browsers
I was wondering how could I make a "rgba"-background using a div with this style:

```
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color: #000;
opacity:0.6;
```

When I left it at this, this div did not show... :(

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A `div` has by default `display: block`, so you don't need to add that. Are the dimensions of the parent set?

Comment: You probably want to look here for a cross-browser css-opacity: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: Define "newer" browsers... `rgba` works with Firefox 3+, Safari 2+, Opera 10+, and all versions of Chrome. It even works with IE8+, provided you include the appropriate IE syntax for IE8 and IE9+.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: IE7+, chrome, safari, and firefox(almost any version really). IE7+ seems to be my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use the inner div to be a background color for the outer div since you are looking for the most cross-browser background opacity.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Based on this article from CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ and the implementation you are looking for you want to use this css:

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    /* IE 5-7 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    /* Netscape */
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    /* Safari 1.x */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    /* Good browsers */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

The inner div has absolute position because if you don't any content you place inside the outer div will be affected by or affect the background inner div.

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Asy/

You can also replace the width and height with:

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

but width and height is fewer properties.

Comment: Your idea worked but now the inner div is larger than the outer div

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle so we can better see the issue you are having.

Comment: I fixed the issue; I originally ignored the "position: relative;" property because that was default, but I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `div` visible by setting an actual width and height, not 100%:

```
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-color: #000;
opacity: 0.6;
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nEw2E/